# how to retrieve date and time separately from the currently selected value in datetimepicker?

Tags: datetimepicker

i want to know the way to extract date and time separately from the currently selected value in datetime picker control??

Answer (score 0):

[`DateTimePicker.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) returns a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), so you can use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) and [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) properties of DateTime.

**Important Note:**

If you're saving the value to a database, put the date value in a data parameter, don't concatenate strings to build SQL queries; that'll leave you open to the SQL injection attack.  Here's a brief example (not tested code, just to give you an idea):

```
DateTime theDate = dtPicker.Value.Date;
IDbCommand command = GetDbCommand("insert into table_name (name, thedate) values (@name, @thedate)");
command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@name", theName));
command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@thedate", theDate));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

More info on avoiding SQL injection attacks (and solving your "invalid month") problem can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx

Comment: when i m using the following statement:
f.trdate='" &DatetimePicker1.value& "' to store it in a database,it shows following error:
not a valid month..
wat to do??

Comment: Might be that it's trying to store the day and month the wrong way round (US format dates are 1/31/2009, UK ones are 31/1/2009, for example). Check regional settings and current culture information.

Comment: Whoa, hang on.  You shouldn't be using the string value in a SQL statement - that'll leave you open to SQL Injection attacks. Use SQL data parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want them for display purposes, you can to the following:

> DateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString() - will give you a date string
>   DateTimePicker.Value.ToShortTimeSttring() - will give you time string

Comment: i dont want it for only display purposes..i have to store these values in the oracle database..
please help

Comment: store them in what format? if it's a varchar field - my method will work just fine for you

Comment: i'm not too familiar with oracle, but looks like you should use DateTimePicker.Value.Date for your Date column, and DateTimePicker.Value.ToShortTimeSttring() for your time column

Comment: Don't store dates in varchar fields - that way lies madness.  There are datetime datatypes in databases for a reason - use them.

Answer (score -1):

DateTimePicker.Value

Worked for me. It shows the date and time.

Comment: Hi there titusx11! Welcome to the site. Please only use the answer box to post actual answers. You can make comments on any of your own posts, but you'll need 50 reputation points to [comment anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: For the moment, I'm flagging this post for deletion.